# Remove elements based off a separate logical vector

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

```
jordan_logical <- grepl("jordan", split_data_raw)
```

```
> jordan_logical
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

I want to remove the elements of the `split_data_raw` based on T or F of another vector.

Comment: What do you mean by "of another list"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[`: `split_data_raw[jordan_logical]`

These are vectors, not `list` objects. `[` does also have a list method.